# MySQL difference between wait_timeout and connect_timeout

Tags: mysql, my.cnf

I have a `my.cnf` file. In it I see `wait_timeout` as well as `connect_timeout`. What's the difference between these 2?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Right from the MySQL Documentation

- [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) : The number of seconds the server waits for activity on a noninteractive connection before closing it.
- [connect_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) : The number of seconds that the mysqld server waits for a connect packet before responding with Bad handshake

**EXAMPLES**

- If [wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) is 1800 (30 Minutes), the DB Connection will close in 30 minutes if the connection is idle (indicated by `Sleep` in the command column of the processlist).
- If [connect_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_connect_timeout) is 10, then mysqld will reject you if you cannot login (authenticate) in 10 seconds.

Comment: There are separate "interactive" and "batch" versions of `wait_timeout`.  Interactive defaults to 8 hours (IIRC); it shows up (at least) when you use the mysql commandline tool.

Comment: concerning `wait_timeout` whats the best way to see how many db connections are idle eg the default seems to be 8 hours so that must there's a lot of connections just hanging around awaiting timeout

Comment: so let's say I have a query that takes 2 minutes to run, would MySQL disconnect my connections if wait_timeout is less than 2 minutes?

Comment: @SoheilRahsaz Anytime a query runs, the idle time start over from scratch. When it is idle for longer than two minutes, then the connection terminates

Answer (score 1):

`wait_timeout` is how long to keep a connection as idle state. `connect_timeout` is how long to wait for a connection to be made.

This is my best understanding, please comment or edit as needed.